# ItemsWrapGrid hides items passed an offset

Tags: gridview, winrt-xaml, virtualization

I am writing a Windows 8.1 Application where I am using a very long `GridView`. I am using UI virtualization, and the view model contains an observable collection with 100K items.

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border 
                Background="LightBlue"
                Height="200" Width="200"
                >
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding Index}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    FontSize="30"
                    />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

On screen it looks like this:
[image]

When using the default items panel (ItemsWrapGrid) and scrolling towards the end of the list, at some point items start disappearing.

[image]

I have tested it with various sizes of items, and the clipping always starts at the same scroll offset (around 2,000,000 pixels). When I replace the panel with a WrapGrid the bug does not happen. I understand that the `ItemsWrapGrid` has a better **virtualization**, and would like to use it, but the bug is of course unacceptable.

Is there a way to resolve this bug while still using `ItemsWrapGrid`?

Comment: I can take a look, can you share your code?

Comment: The question contains all the code you need. Just set the data context to any class containing a property called Items holding 1000000 objects and you will see it.

Comment: I run out of memory when the view tries to render. That is, after my Observable collection is populated and the xaml view starts to display, I get System.OutOfMemoryException. Are you doing anything in particular to avoid an OutOfMemoryException?

Answer (score 1):

just after posting my OutOfMemoryException quandary, I did a little bit more research and I think I have a solution for you, I found this:

> The concept of a viewport is critical to UI virtualization because the
>   framework must create the elements that are likely to be shown. In
>   general, the viewport of an ItemsControl is the extent of the logical
>   control. For example, the viewport of a ListView is the width and
>   height of the ListView element. Some panels allow child elements
>   unlimited space, examples being ScrollViewer and a Grid, with
>   auto-sized rows or columns. When a virtualized ItemsControl is placed
>   in a panel like that, it takes enough room to display all of its
>   items, which defeats virtualization. Restore virtualization by setting
>   a width and height on the ItemsControl.
>   [ListView and GridView UI optimization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204776.aspx)

So I added this to your GridView ItemsSource:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Width="800" Height="800">
```

It looks like it needed a Width and Height.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the GridView sits inside a container that does have a width and height (its not a scroll viewer or anyithing that gives it infinite space). In fact, the virtualization works! I am using a special type of observable collection that creates its item lazily, so I know for sure that the virtualization itself works (it also answers your first question about how to avoid memory problems). The only issue is that it does not present items passed the 2000000 pixels width.

Comment: How do you check for a "2000000 pixels width"? But that seems to go against the viewport idea which would limit the pixels to inside the viewport?

Comment: Anyway, I thought this was interesting as I had not needed to write something to use virtualization. I think the concept as explained by Microsoft and lazy loading the collection are two different things. Virtualization as defined by Microsoft seems designed to avoid trying to display "2000000 pixels".